# find the draggable list item position based on table while dropped on a table

Tags: jquery-ui

I have created a draggable list item which can be drooped on a table. While dropped on a table cell display the left most (ie, `tbody` `tr` `td:first-child`) and top most (ie: `thead` `tr` `th:first-child`) position value of a table on. Every drop of draggable item on table show its left most and top most position. Also, while dragging a list item and dropped on table, make it further daraggable within table cell and find its position based on table column value (left most) and table row value (top most).

I have already drag a list item on a table cell and further it is draggable in table but the original drag item remains which is not I have  required, I want to drag the same original draggable element and drop on another table cell.

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('ready');

  var $listItem=$('#sort1 li');             
  $(  $listItem ).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    appendTo: "body",
    refreshPositions: true
  });           
  $( "#sort1" ).selectable();           
  $( "#sort1" ).disableSelection();             
  var $container=$("#dropdiv table tbody td  ");
  console.log($($container));
  initDroppable($($container  ));

  function initDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)", 
      over: function (event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this); //console.log($this)
      }, drop:function (event, ui) {    
        var $this = $(this);    
        console.log(ui.position)        
        var $item = ui.draggable.clone();   
        $item.draggable({       cancel:"a.ui-icon",         
        revert: 'invalid',      
        cursor: "move",         
        appendTo: "body",
      });   
      $(this).addClass('has-drop').append($item);
      console.log($item.attr('id')) } })            }           
      var $trash=$(' #sort1  li button ');          
      $( $trash ).droppable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon",
        revert: "invalid", 
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        appendTo: "body",
        refreshPositions: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
          var drag_id = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
          var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");
          deleteMe = true;            
          $(this)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("p")
            .html("Dropped! inside " + targetElem);
          $(ui.helper).remove(); //destroy clone
          $(ui.draggable).remove(); //remove from list    
        },    
        over:function(event,ui){
          console.log($(this));
        }
      });
    }       
  });   
</script>
```

mycode: https://jsfiddle.net/23ptag8j/17/

Answer (score 0):

It was reasonably clear what you wanted, but it just seemed sort of weird. Consider the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mkz1xLy0/62/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="right">
    <div id="dropdiv">
      <table border="3 " class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Day/shift</th>
            <th id="shift1">7:15-8:45</th>
            <th id="shift2">8:45-9:30</th>
            <th id="shift3">9:30-10:15</th>
            <th id="shift4">11:00-11:45</th>
            <th id="shift5">11:45-12:30</th>
            <th id="shift6">12:30-13:15</th>
            <th id="shift7">1:15-14:00</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="body">
          <tr id="con1" class="sortConn">
            <td id="row">Sunday</td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default " id="1"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="2"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="3"></span> </td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="4"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="5"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="6"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="7"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="con2" class="sortConn">
            <td id="row">Monday</td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default " id="8"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="9"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="10"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="11"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="12"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="13"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="14"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="con3" class="sortConn">
            <td id="row">Tuesday</td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="15"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="16"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="17"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="18"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="19"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="20"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="21"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="con4" class="sortConn">
            <td id="row">Wednesday</td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="22"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="23"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="24"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="25"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="26"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="27"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="28"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="con5" class="sortConn">
            <td id="row">Thrusday</td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="29"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="30"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="31"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="32"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="33"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="34"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="35"></span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="con6" class="sortConn">
            <td id="row">Friday</td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="36"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="37"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="38"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="39"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="40"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="41"></span></td>
            <td class="span drop"><span class="ui-state-default" id="42"></span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="drag-list">
    <div id="origin" class="card">
      <ul id="sort-1" class="list">
        <li id="one">English</li>
        <li id="two">Nepali</li>
        <li id="three">Economics</li>
      </ul>
      <button>Trash</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  height: 340px;
  width: 232px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#sort-1 {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#sort-1 li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.list {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.drag-card {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.drop-card {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 98%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function makeDrag(el, clone) {
    if (clone == undefined) {
      clone = false;
    }
    var $d = $(el).draggable({
      cancel: "a.ui-icon",
      revert: "invalid",
      containment: ".container",
      helper: function(e) {
        if (clone) {
          var cnt = $(e.target).text();
          return $("<div>", {
            class: "drag-card"
          }).html(cnt);
        }
        return $(e.target);
      },
      cursor: "move",
      appendTo: "body",
      refreshPositions: true
    });
    return $d;
  }
  var $listItem = $('#sort-1 li');
  makeDrag($listItem, true);
  $("#sort-1").selectable();
  $("#sort-1").disableSelection();
  var $dropItems = $("#dropdiv .drop");
  initDroppable($dropItems);

  function initDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $item = $("<div>", {
            class: "drop-card"
          })
          .html(ui.helper.text());
        $("span", $this).append($item);
        makeDrag($item);
        ui.helper.remove();
      }
    })
  }
  var $trash = $('#drag-list button');
  $trash.button({
      icon: "ui-icon-trash"
    })
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var retval = confirm("Are you sure you want to empty the trash?");
      if (retval) {
        // Empty Trash
        $trash.removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    })
    .droppable({
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var drag_id = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");
        deleteMe = true;
        $(this)
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
          .find("p")
          .html("Dropped! inside " + targetElem);
        ui.helper.remove();
        ui.draggable.remove();
      }
    });
});
```

Here are the conditions I was working off of:

- A card from the drag-list can be dragged into the table; when dropped, that item is appended to that cell, the original remains
- A item that is appended to a cell should be draggable after drop
- When moving an item from cell to cell, the origin should be removed
- When dragging an item to "Trash", the original should be removed

The things I did to help this:

- Added `drop` class to all the cells that should allow the item to be dropped
- Created single function `makeDrag` to make elements draggable with a `clone` condition that defaults to `false`
- Added unique ID to each `drop` cell for proper HTML Syntax

**Update**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mkz1xLy0/69/

I added the following to the `drop` callback:

```
$this.droppable("disable");
makeDrag($item);
$item.on("dragstart", function(e, ui){
  $item.closest(".drop").droppable("enable");
});
```

As you can see, we disable the drop function when an item is dropped. We then re-enable it in the `dragstart` event.

I hope this fits with your design and is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks alot  for the answer .Also ,I have another question .Donot drop a draggable elemnt (Li-item) on a droppable table cell if  already item being dropped .

Comment: @pokharelsamir you can just disable droppable when an item is dropped. Then enable it again when drag completes.

Comment: i have tried to disable the droppable whenever it  already contains the draggable element using this line of code  // if( $(this)..find(ui.draggable.attr('id){
   //      $(this).droppable('disable');
   //  }else{$(this).droppable('enable')}
inside a drop function ,and also you know we have Trash button .After removing the  element ,i want the same droppable container to be re-enable for drooping purpose .I knew about  'enabaling  the droppable container but i am stuck where to use it .

Comment: your updated answer works .Meanwhile,I would like to swap the draggable elements after it has been dropped on the  droppable container ( i,e :table) .

Comment: @pokharelsamir that sounds like a new question. If this answers your current question, I would mark it as the answer. Then try to work on your new swap feature. If you get stuck, search about some or post a new question.

Comment: Twisty  i will search  a post for swappable feature but the previous answer doesn't works well .i,e; the closest droppable container (table cell) allows to drop the element even if already contains an element which i donot want to be .i have provided a link. you can view it .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ikAaMaLz1goBNFoP4_Af_QA6KKI-YuKi/view

Comment: @pokharelsamir your image does not make a lot of sense. It might be best to update your post with the code you are now using. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Twisty while re-enabaling the droppable container using  $item.closest(".drop").droppable("enable");

Comment: Twisty while re-enabaling the droppable container using  $item.closest(".drop").droppable("enable"); ,it enables to drop more than one draggable element  (the provided image is about this ).I want to re-enable the closest dropped container(i,e; td) which works fine  but it allows to drop more than one draggable element .If it already contains the draggable element ,i want the respective droppable container (i,e;td) to check it before dropping .I mean if the  element already exist donot allow to drop on it .

Comment: @pokharelsamir something doesn't add up there. When droppable is enabled, it would accept a dropped item and in that drop callback it disables drop. So there is no way for it to accept another item. Since you have not updated your post, I have no way to know what code you're currently using. Please update you post with your complete example of current code. Or add a new code pen / fiddle.

Comment: .yes ,its true it doesn't accept the item from the draggable list but it will accept the cloned draggable item(i;e;already dropped draggabble item) .Here ,is the link of a current code i have been using .https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwQeXP

Comment: @pokharelsamir I had to do a bunch of cleanup and fix a lot of syntax issues. It appears to work as expected. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgXoej?editors=0010#0

Comment: Twisty can you try to swap between the table cells items (i,e:the item being already dropped ),you will see the issue ,i am trying to fix and tell about .Try this: Drag and drop 2 elements from draggable item to droppable cell on different table cells and try  to drop those elements within each other .